# Which one is better between static block or Spring autowired?

Tags: java, spring, static

There are two ways to get the Client Instance ,but I don't know which one is better , and why?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't know what your use case is or metric for "better".  But static means a single client.  A Spring Bean can be pooled.  You don't want a single database connection unless there's always just one user.

Comment: StackOverflow lets you post code in the question.  Please don't post screenshots of code.  Especially not with a black background--I can't read it unless I tilt my laptop screen a certain way and move my head so that my neck hurts.  Also the screenshot cuts off one of your code lines at the right.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion , I just too lazy to copy code and format them...

Comment: Given the choice I would almost always go with dependency injection. One reason is it makes testing easier as you can mock your dependency, mocking static singletons is much harder to do.

Comment: Please paste the relevant in your question rather than using screenshots. More info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is much worse. Making something a singleton is very inflexible, everything that uses it is tied to this implementation and can't be exercised independently of it.

A singleton is hardwired global state that anything in your application can call, so objects don't declare their dependencies and it's hard to know what anything depends on. See this article http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/ for more explanation.

Dependency injection frameworks were invented to give developers a better way to connect objects than through static references or service locators. Having singleton-ness enforced by the framework instead of the code allows for easier substitution of mocks.

In the first example the constructor call and static method calls that try to resolve hostnames make testing harder. But getClient is an instance method that can be overridden in a test. The second example is worse because the problem is broader,  everything that uses the singleton is hard to test.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I also like to use DI in code ,but I often see the second way in the others's code , so I have the question.